# Error while creating a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, 2016

I have migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016.

I get "Sorry something went wrong" error while creating list. But finally the list is created. This happens only in one site collection and it works just fine in other site collection in the same web application.

**Below is the error message from ULS logs:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection.GetSqlToAddEventReceivers(Guid
>   siteId, Guid webId, Guid hostId, SPEventHostType hostType, Byte[]
>   sourceId, Guid solutionId, SPEventReceiverSource sourceType)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.FixEventReceivers(Guid lid)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateListFromRpc(NameValueCollection
>   queryString, Uri& nextUrl)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewListPage.BtnOk_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

How to resolve this issue or Any idea why this error occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an event receiver can not been Authenticated . Found if you have custom content type or event receiver , if yes , remove them and re-create list again .

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps .

Comment: I am not using some solutions in my new environment, but seems like some of the event receiver definitions are still in the database and SharePoint is trying to attach them when a list is created which causes the error. Can you please tell me how to clear or remove the faulty event  receiver definitions.

Answer (score 1):

have you uninstalled some customized feature or solution? It seens that sharepoint is expecting some event reeceiver definition that is not there